# mongoose schema type for country phone code prefix e.g '+44'

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema, mongoose-schema

What is the best type to store a phone country code in a MongoDB schema? Would it simply be a String? I am storing the code separately to the phone number and will simply concatenate the two when required.

Currently, the schema is as below:

```
// Contact number schema
const contactNoSchema = {
  type: String,
  trim: true,
  default: '',
  match: [/^\+?\d+[\d\s]+$/, 'Please fill a valid telephone number']
};


//Country prefix code
const prefixCode = {
  type: String
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Phone number with extensions are recommended to be separated into two columns, both being String. Do not use integer type for any of the two as the length may vary and you may or may not want to store formatted data in the future.